# How to use object inside functions php

Tags: php, laravel

I have defined services and DAO class (to access DB) in my laravel projects. I need to create an object of the class that can access through functions. Here is the way I tried it? but it's not working

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\DAO\CategoryDAO;

$categoryDAO = new CategoryDAO();

function categoryReadAll()
{

    return $CategoryDAO->categoryReadAll();

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is "this"? Looks like a pretty usual way of global variables which should be avoided nowadays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\DAO\CategoryDAO;

$categoryDAO = new CategoryDAO();
$GLOBALS['categoryDAO'] = $categoryDAO;

function categoryReadAll() {

    return $GLOBALS['categoryDAO']->categoryReadAll();

}
```

[Check the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Or:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\DAO\CategoryDAO;

$categoryDAO = new CategoryDAO();

function categoryReadAll() {
    global $categoryDAO;
    return $categoryDAO->categoryReadAll();

}
```

Hope help you.

Comment: Thank you very much. Only the second one works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Also, this one works fine

```
  $GLOBALS['auctionHouseDAO'] = new AuctionHouseDAO(); 

  function createAuctionHouse($request) { 
      global $auctionHouseDAO;
      return $auctionHouseDAO->createAuctionHouse($request); 
 }
```